# Git directory vs SVN directory

Tags: git, svn

In SVN, I can create a repository called

```
myserver/myprojects
```

then I can push a new project, called `abcproject` to the repository above.  It becomes:

```
myserver/myprojects/abcproject
```

Is it similar for git?  If I do:

```
cd abcproject
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git remote add origin myname@myserver/myprojects
git push origin master
```

what will happen?  Is my local `abcproject` stored in `myprojects` directory like with SVN, or do I have to create the local project called `myprojects`, the same name as the remote, and then `push`?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Remote git pushes are between repositories.

You create a "bare" repository on the server. Then you clone that repository on the client. The clone creates a second repository - the client-side one.

Then you make commits on the client and push from the client repository to the server one.

Pushing *never* creates a new repository. It only sends changes from one that already exists to another one that already exists.

In the example you gave, you didn't run "git init" on the server, so you're going to get an error that there's no git repository at the path you specified on the remote end.

Comment: Sorry, the git init is on client.  Sounds to me that remote repo has to have same name on local (client) repo.

Comment: @user2543991 A repository doesn't have a name. A repository is just a `.git` directory. You can call it whatever you want.